# Why 7805 regulator gives output 6 volt?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, 7805, lm78xx

I am using 7805 and 7815 for the voltage 5 V and 15 V respectively. I provide 24 V to 7815 it is giveinng me output voltage 18.5 V instead of 15 V. According to 18.5 V to input to 7805, its output is 6 V. It should have to provide 5 V output. similarly, the output of 7815 should be 15 V.

I don't know what is happening. Can you tell me what will be the error in the circuit?

[image]

I am using this schematic in hardware.

Comment: With no load the regulators will find it hard to regulate. Connect it to a simple resistive load (say a 1KΩ resistor) and measure the voltage then.

Comment: That doesn't really qualify as a full schematic. "_Can you tell me what will be the error in the circuit?_" Not with the little information you gave.

Comment: +1 for @Majenko. Give it a dummy load and see how the voltage changes. Maybe try a 1k pot and gradually decrease the resistance (increasing the current) to see how Vout changes.

Comment: @Jim Until the pot catches fire as you hit the last few mm of track... ;)

Comment: I've always wondered what the point is of putting a 'cap before the regulator.

Comment: I've seen a 7905 give too high an output without a load, but never a 7805.  Not sure what that means.

Comment: Is it possible that your meter is off?  A 1 volt error at 5 volts and a 3.5 volt error at 15 volts suggest this possibility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a minimum load for them to regulate. Add a resistor to give 100 uA of load and the situation should improve.

Answer (score 19):

Your circuit is fine. The battery in your meter needs to be replaced.

The voltmeter is reading high by more than 20% because the internal voltage reference has gone out of regulation (low) and the readings are a ratio like Reading = K * Vin/Vref.

Comment: If OP accepts this you will earn +1 for mindreading.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is dead but I had the *exact same* issue.
Turns out I had the chip backwards. [image: L7805cv]